# Trying to install ImageMagick, but when running sudo apt-get update it requires a password, what should I do? what password do I need?

Tags: imagemagick

Does anyone know what to do in this case? Like I said, I'm trying to download imagemagick from the command line, but to do so, I need to run this command: sudo apt-get update. But everytime I do, it asks for a password. Where/what is this password? where could i find out this password?

Comment: It is asking for your login password to authenticate!

Comment: i don't know what my login password is, that's what I'm saying. I've never set one up.

Comment: How exactly did you set up your machine? Did you use the "normal" installation CDs / DVDs / ISOs, or are we talking about a system customized to maybe a hypervisor like OpenVZ or LXC?

Answer (score 1):

If it asks "[sudo] password for *username*" just use your login password

If you never dowloaded it before the command would be

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Comment: somehow I changed the password to my psql and now I can't access my user account. I don't understand clearly how I did this. NOw I just want to know how I can either get that password or uninstall and reinstall postgres